# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: java, hibernate

This is the error I am getting. I have been stuck for 2 hours but could not resolve it.My code for hibernate is as follows:-

```
Session session1=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory().openSession();

        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration cfg=new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        //creating seession factory object
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        //creating session object
        Session session=factory.openSession();

        String hql = "SELECT E.id FROM User E where firstName=:name";
        SQLQuery query = session1.createSQLQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        List results = query.list();
        Iterator itr=results.iterator();
        String id="";
        while(itr.hasNext()){ id=String.valueOf(itr.next());}

        //creating transaction object
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();



        User employee =
                (User)session.get(User.class, 2);
        employee.setMessage(chat);
        session.update(employee);


        //template.save(e1);

        //session.persist(user);//persisting the object

        t.commit();//transaction is committed
        session.close();
        return "hello";
```

Any help would be appreciated..thanx in advance.

My full stack trace is as follows:-

```
Stack Trace
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:74
```

5)

Comment: Show full stacktrace, but I think you have to qualify `firstName`, i.e. `E.firstName`.

Comment: thanx Andreas, you r correct. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String hql = "SELECT u.id FROM User u where u.firstName = :name";
    Query query = session1.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("name", name);
    List results = query.getResultList();
    Iterator itr=results.iterator();
    String id="";
    while(itr.hasNext()){ id=String.valueOf(itr.next());}
```